# SpriteKit - SKScene bounds are not equal to SKView bounds

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

Recently I've created a new Xcode - Game project. Without touching anything I ran the template. I was expecting a standard *Hello World!* app, but I noticed one thing. Instead of pretty filled background, I got scene *cut* at the top and the bottom.

How can I make it fill the whole screen?

[image: attached image]

Comment: It looks like it is a SafeArea. Hard to tell more without additional information - preferably add the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So let me explain. Whenever you create a brand new game project in Xcode, you get a Hello World template (animation of scaling label, and colorful hexagons on touches bagan). Background is bounded to view.frames.bounds, but in my case is's  cut at bottom and top. I've attached an image to main post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the default SpriteKit Game template is missing a Launch Screen. You need to add it manually:

1. Add a Launch Screen:

New File -> iOS -> User Interface  -> Launch Screen

2. Set the name of your new launch screen in:

[Your Project] -> General -> Launch Screen File